# python/django: How to detect and avoid import name conflict?

Tags: python, django, import, conflict

I had an that I need some help.
In my django application, I have this code:

```
from django.template import Context

render_dict = {'scan': oval_scan, 'user': user, 'vulns': oval_vulns, 'asset_vulns': asset_vulns}
report_html = get_template('oval_report.html').render(Context(render_dict))
```

However, django gave me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/nopsec/nopsecvrm/apps/pegasus/views.py", line 2359, in ovalReport
    report_html = get_template('pegasus/oval_report.html').render(Context(render_dict))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 121, in render
    context.render_context.push()
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'render_context'
```

I remembered that I met this error once because there is another `Context` somewhere else in another import package, which was used by mistake, so I change my code like this(very ugly but works):

```
import django

render_dict = {'scan': oval_scan, 'user': user, 'vulns': oval_vulns, 'asset_vulns': asset_vulns}
report_html = get_template('report.html').render(django.template.Context(render_dict))
```

My question is: How can I determine which `Context` did django use by mistake by looking at the traceback error? How can I resolve this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to avoid the conflict by aliasing the `Context` that you import:

```
from django.template import Context as template_context
```

Then just refer to template_context when you need the version you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__import__` function from the `__builtins__` module:

```
#Detecting name conflicts:
module_name_as_string = 'mymodule'

if module_name_as_string in globals(): #we have name collision
   try:
      custom_module = __import__(module_name_as_string)
   except ImportError:
      pass
```